# Exit a thread upon app unload

Tags: java

I maintain a library that starts a daemon thread to do work in the background. In regular Java and Android applications, this thread is started once and runs for the lifetime of the process. It never exits and that's okay.

When my library is included in an application container that supports application unloading (such as Tomcat), the application never unloads. My running thread holds strong references to its own class and that prevents the entire application from being unloaded. Users of my library cannot hot-swap their app without leaking memory each time.

**What's the best way to get signaled when the application container wishes to unload my library?**

This is a small library without any dependency on application container APIs. It doesn't know which application container it's running in and it doesn't want to!

The fact that this library starts a thread is an implementation detail. End users of the library shouldn't have to know that a thread is being started, and it is not their responsibility to shut it down.

Comment: Is there some other object you could detect the garbage collection of?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your problem correctly but maybe this: https://weblogs.java.net/blog/kcpeppe/archive/2011/09/29/mysterious-phantom-reference will be helpful?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can't you determine if your lib was used by the application in the last x minutes / seconds and shutdown the thread if not? Restart it on next use? The `java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor` works this way.

Comment: This can work. It's unfortunate to stall process eviction, but not unworkable.

Answer (score 7):

Your best bet is to provide a method to clean up the library. The end user will have to call it (presumably based on handling application lifecycle in the container). You could also provide a `Listener` for those cases when it is used in a compatible servlet container (e.g., Tomcat), but your end user will still have to be aware and put the descriptor in the web.xml.

The only other alternative is that your end user is going to have to create a Listener that manages to get the thread to die. I have had to do this on several occasions and it is not pretty. It usually involves using reflection to get ahold of the thread and killing it. Of course, the ThreadDeath exception is handled by some libraries and the threads refuse to die. This then requires more significant use of reflection to clean up the mess.

Your end users are much better off if you give them an easy way to clean up the library. It sucks that they have to know about your implementation details, but they already do because you are keeping the app from unloading.

Comment: I would prefer that future users of my library don't have to discover that their apps aren't unloading and then have to search for fix. Much better if it just works!

Comment: @JesseWilson I agree completely! However, the reality is that there is no automatic and reliable way to detect that you are running in a webapp let alone when that app is getting unloaded. It is better to make it easy for the user to deal with this than leave it as a painful problem to work around.

Comment: Perhaps you could offer this API (for immediate cleanup by informed consumers), *as well as* providing some kind of automated time-out based approach like @Cfx suggests for (uninformed consumers).

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting problem.  One idea you may want to try:

Have the daemon thread use weak references to your library.  Then have some guard object in the library have it's `finalize()` method take down the daemon thread.

Would something like that work?

Comment: Unfortunately, the library holds no references back to the application, so that approach won't work for me.

Comment: Jesse - Ah - I think I may have caused some confusion with my use of the term 'application'.  I meant your library. I'm pretty sure that the strategy I described will work.  I'll change the text of my response to make that more clear.

Comment: The garbage collector isn't capable of signaling that the app has unloaded. Values are collected too early (before unload); classes too late (after my thread exits).

Answer (score 1):

You can use ComponentCallbacks2.onTrimMemory(). This is called when the system is low on resources and the app in background should release resources.

My experience is that when onTrimMemory(TRIM_MEMORY_COMPLETE) is called then the app is about to be killed.

Comment: I'm specifically interested in cases where the process keeps running, but the application inside of it is unloaded. ComponentCallbacks won't help because Android doesn't implement unloading classes.